# How to design a C# application if the same method has to use different version of references?

Tags: c#, reflection, inversion-of-control

I am wondering anyone can give me a hint on how to design this scenario:

In C#, Program A is calling a reference assembly B's method C. However, later this assembly B's code was changed and that method is renamed to something else like D. How could a program work to support both different version of assembly B without build two different version of Program A?

Is reflection the only way out? Any other suggestion? I am not familiar with IoC, but is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Is Assembly B Source code is within your access? Or is it outside your scope?

Comment: It is still a inhouse component , but in my case, it is out of my team's scope. So we can't update it.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, using reference to different versions of same assembly withing one class is not possible at all (or even in one assembly). Try thinking about class names colliding, as they appear to be the same, even if they have different implementation. 
So i would recommend to stack to one version and use adaptor pattern (on level of different assembly) or other technics to resolve your issue.

And actually, using different versions of same assembly is always a pain and I would strongly recommend not going that way.

Comment: thanks. I think I have idea on how to use the Adapter pattern. But looks like I still need to implement reflection in order to 'choose' which version in this case without compiler error?

Comment: yes, reflection is basically the only way, if you want to reference two different versions of one assembly. But still, you won't be able to "export" types from those assembly, which means you cant use those types  as return type of method, as compiler needs a strong type for return types and arguments. The only thing you can do here - do all the stuff with reflection inside of the method, and return some known type outside.

Comment: But, as i mentioned above, if you use adaptor patter **outside** the assembly, you can do, that you want, with same limitations I mentioned above (return type or arguments), but without reflection at all. Let me explain. Suppose you assembly "A" is your working assembly, and assembly "B" is one, that has different versions.  Now you create assembly "C", reference there other version of assembly "B", use code from "B" and expose outside anything, but code from "B". And after you just use assembly "C" within "A". That way "A" and "C" will be working with different versions of same assembly.

Comment: Yura, I appreciated your comment... I think I understand the trick.. let me try it.